why does transiesta calculation time increase with the voltage during transport properties calculation?
In my research, I used semiconductors as channel materials and metals as electrodes to calculate the transport properties under different bias voltages.
I found that the calculation time kept increasing with the increase of bias voltage, and it was not a linear increase. At 1.8V, the calculation time was twice that of 1.7V.
Why does transiesta calculation time increase with the voltage during transport properties calculation?

There are various implications of increasing the voltage.

The first, directly impactable variable is the number of energy points on the non-equilibrium contour. Which, for higher bias, has more energy points. There is no way around this. So, generally a $V=2V'$ should take twice as long.

Then comes the SCF cycles of the actual calculation.
The most important factor, is that the closests TSDE file gets copied in before the calculation starts. This will enable transiesta to restart the calculation from an electronic structure, close to the target bias.
I.e. if you have done a 1.7 V calcualtion, then copy that 1.7 TSDE file, into the 1.8 directory, and you should see that it starts from that point.

The electronic structure is also very susceptible to hitting band-edges at increased bias'. Basically if there are no on-sets of bands at 1.7 V. But you have a band-onset at 1.8 V, then there will be a large charge-fluctuation taking place. In these cases, sometimes it can be benificial to increase the bias slightly, so that one does not hit any band-onsets, preferably go into a band. This is hard to detect before the calculation is running, but trial-and-error is the only friend here. So perhaps doing a 1.9 V calculation is simpler. If this works better, then omitting the 1.8 V calculation is the simplest.

Mixing weights are very important here, decreasing them could be a potential solution, but that will also increase the # of SCF steps.


There are probably more factors, but the above tends to be the most common factors.
